# Find user/process blocking a network share folder

Tags: windows, network-shares, blocking

I have a folder on a network share which I wish to rename.

Some process still seems to have a handle in at least one file in that folder, for which reason I get a 'Access denied' message or dialog, you know what I'm speaking of.

Now I've looked around, and there seem to be only dodgy programs available and Microsoft's own ProcessExplorer. Unfortunately, when I search for handles with the ProcessExplorer, I can only find handles of processes that run ***on my machine***. But that does not help for the network share, because some other user and machine is blocking the access.

So, how do I find out who is locking a file in that folder?

Answer (score 3):

Select 'Manage' in the right click menu of 'My Computer' (or Computer) on the machine hosting the shared file, then under 'Shared Folders', go to 'Sessions' and look for your file. It will tell you there who has it open. You can also kill any connection to the file from there. You'll need to be logged in as a local administrator of that machine to be able to do that.